# Angular-Datatables + Angular-xeditable : editable row canceled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables, angular-xeditable

When combining angular-datatables and angular-xeditable, editable row is canceled when adding a new row.

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faj61h5d/10/).
Sample operation is as follows.

(1) ***This is initial state.***

[image]

(2) ***editing first and third rows to status "status4".***

[image]

(3) ***Press `Add row`.***

[image]

On `(3)`, editting is canceled and status is reverted to "status1". My hope is both row1 and row3 are kept editting and status stays "status4". If without angular-datatables, it works as my hope as [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/NfPcH/19059/), but I would like to use with datatables.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had a DataTables table in Angular that I needed to make inline editable - [this CellEdit plugin](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit) and its basic initialization code worked like a charm! Not sure if it supports adding new rows and deleting rows, though.

Hope this helps!